# sudo move config file in unaccesable dir

Tags: php, exec, sudo

I'm trying to "rewrite" a config file somewhere on my server

```
if ($return = exec("sudo mv.sh '/etc/my/config.cfg' '/etc/my/config.cfg.bak'",$output)){
     echo 'Yaaay';
}
else {
print_r($output);
print_r($return);
die('Couldn\'t move original config file');
}
```

the dir  /etc/my is owned by the server but i tried adding the following lines to my /etc/sudoers file:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: /var/www/mysite/mv.sh
www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/etc/my/
```

Now i am using a shell script file, which is owned by www-data in the root of my site, but i have also tried a mv by itself.

This is the content of the shell script

```
$FILE1 = $1
$FILE2 = $2
mv $FILE1 $FILE2
```

I also tried putting sudo in front of the mv command in there but that doesn't work either..

I would love it if i could move this file as backup, and then after that i would like to recreate the file putting some contents into it, that i posted...

```
   file_put_contents('/etc/my/config.cfg', $_POST['contents']);
```

Now i don't get any errors and `$output` and `$return` come back empty. I do get my failure message

```
'Couldn\'t move original config file'
```

Comment: You realise that putting your `www-data` user in sudoers means that anyone who gains control over your webserver has root on your box, right? One file upload extension bug and your entire system is owned.

Comment: i do realize that, and i don't want to give them blank access, but i want to at least make it work and after that filter out the access it doesn't need

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this way?

```
www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/var/www/mysite/mv.sh
```

And call mv.sh with absolute path in the php exec?

If there is any problem with sudo try the script at first manually. su to www-data and try to run the same command:

```
sudo /var/www/mysite/mv.sh '/etc/my/config.cfg' '/etc/my/config.cfg.bak'
```

Comment: the straight command works fine... but i get the same result from the browser

Comment: i have changed my shell script to contain the params i was sending and i change the path used to ./mv.sh and now it works, Thanks, you made me rethink it a little!